# iPad Safari ignores prime and double prime chars if using custom font

Tags: css, ipad, fonts, safari, font-face

iPad Safari doesn't show feet (`′` = `\u2032`) and inch (`″` = `\u2033`) signs ([prime](http://unicode-table.com/en/2032/) and [double prime](http://unicode-table.com/en/2033/), according to unicode specification) when using [Anago](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/positype/anago/) font.

As I understand, this font doesn't contain corresponding symbols, but desktop browsers (including Safari on Mac) show them in default font. By some reason iPad behaves in the other way.

Also I checked the other chars not presented in the fiont (replaced latin `ace` via cyrillic `асе`), And they were shown using default font (see bellow).

What's the problem with these two chars?
**How I can force them shown in default font?**

```html
<!doctype html>

<meta charset=utf-8>

<title>iOS Safari doesn't render feet and inches</title>

<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: "Anago";
  src: url("Positype - Anago-Book.otf");
  font-weight: 300;
}

body {
  font-family: Anago, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4em;
}
</style>

<p>Just a test - latin</p>
<p>Just а tеst - lаtin аnd сyrilliс</p>
<p>5′ 9.7″</p>
<p style="font-family: sans-serif">5′ 9.7″</p>
```

Desktop Chrome on Windows:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Desktop Safari on Mac:

[image: Safari screenshot]

Safari on iPad:

[image: iPad screenshot]

Other iPad browsers behave like iPad Safiri.

[FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) shows following for these chars:

[image: FontForge screenshot]

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/582261/178988)

Comment: Point of precision: those are the Unicode prime and double prime symbols, and not the "feet symbol" and "inches symbol". While the foot and inch units do indeed *use* the prime and double prime symbol, the Unicode name, and the documentation around them when you're trying to find out whether they're supported or not, are almost always based on their real name, not the names of the role we've overloaded those symbols with =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, updated the question. What do you mean by supporting them? The are shown in system font, but by some reason ignored in custom. Ignored on iPad only...

Comment: Fonts are [rather complex bits of software](http://pomax.github.io/CFF-glyphlet-fonts), they're not "a collection of pictures", they're more like game ROMs - *all* the information to do typesetting is in the font, and depending on how it structures things internally iOS might (correctly or incorrectly) flag parts of it as bad and thus to be ignored. Run your font through some validators (I recommend TTX and trying to load it in FontForge, possibly even compile https://github.com/HinTak/Font-Validator and see what that says)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, updated the question.

Comment: So here's a thing to test: while the font does not list glyphs for those codepoints, what does its cmap segment coverage claim? Because if the segment coverage mistakenly claims support for those codepoints, then a bad CSS engine might stop at Anago and resolve the glyph, getting nothing, where a better CSS engine might do the same, see the glyphs don't resolve, and then move on to the next font. Probably worth checking with [TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) (and perhaps Font Validator) to rule out possible causes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, `Dumping 'GlyphOrder' table...
Dumping 'head' table...
Dumping 'hhea' table...
Dumping 'maxp' table...
Dumping 'OS/2' table...
Dumping 'name' table...
Dumping 'cmap' table...
Dumping 'post' table...
Dumping 'CFF ' table...
Dumping 'GPOS' table...
Dumping 'GSUB' table...
Dumping 'hmtx' table...
Dumping 'kern' table...` - What should I search for?

Comment: open the XML file that the dump was written to (same name as the font, just with `.xml` extension) and find the `<cmap>` section, then run through that to see if it actually has entries in any of the subtables for those u2032/u2033 codepoints.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, `0x203` is presented only as part of `<map code="0x2030" name="perthousand"/>
<!--  PER MILLE SIGN  -->
<map code="0x2039" name="guilsinglleft"/>
<!--  SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK  -->
<map code="0x203a" name="guilsinglright"/>
<!--  SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK  -->
<map code="0x203c" name="exclamdbl"/>
<!--  DOUBLE EXCLAMATION MARK  -->
<map code="0x203d" name="interrobang"/>` twice.

Comment: that's good information to put in the post and clear the comments for, so that people can see that this is not the font itself being the problem - it has no cmap entry for these characters and for all intents and purposes should be ignored for typesetting prime/double prime characters.